# Parenting a camera and an empty cube not working the way I need it to for rigging

Tags: rigging

When I align the camera and the empty together so that the camera is in the centre of the empty, they both move together despite them being un-parented. Then when I parent them together the child object (the camera) moves away faster than the empty cube (the parent). Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here are some images I took:

Top image: The parented objects before hitting G and moving them around.

Middle image: The camera has moved faster and further away from the empty cube which is its parent after moving.

EDIT: When I open up a completely new blender file it works just fine, so I've got no idea what is going on.

EDIT 2: I've solved it I had proportional editing on, I'm so stupid!

Bottom image: When I hit Alt P and un-parent, the two objects still move together for some reason.
[image: The parented objects before hitting G and moving them around.]

[image: The camera has moved faster and further away from the empty cube which is its parent after moving.]

[image: When I hit Alt P and un-parent, the two objects still move together for some reason.]

Comment: On the screen captures, the 'constraints' tab is selected... nothing configured there?

Comment: I'm a bit of a beginner, could you explain a bit more what that is?

Comment: Never mind I know what you mean, nothing is set up there.

Comment: Always a good idea to include the outliner in the screenshots, as the empty constraint tab could as well be from another object. In the outliner constraints are shown behind the object-name. And even an empty by itself can connect 2 other objects to achieve what you have trouble with. Thus my suggestion is to look through the outliner and see if there is any setup be it an empty or other object that has constrains on it. While the second picture shows a parent or constraint line, the third picture can't help as the objects are on the same location and a dotted line thus isn't visible.

Comment: Hi. https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/ should help with taking clearer screenshots.

Comment: Apologies, I'll  update it with new screenshots